# Firebase: "Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Cloud Datastore projects"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was running into an issue where the node `Firebase Admin SDK` was throwing this error, when I was trying to access the Firestore API on a locally spun up server (for debugging):

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Cloud Datastore projects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future Googler's the problem was that I was trying to initialize the `Firebase Admin SDK` using this method, which apparently only works in the Google Cloud environment:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Even though that command doesn't fail, it won't let you connect to Firebase's Firestore... frustrating.

Here's the correct method of initialization:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

Hope this helps someone (including future me)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I already have this method on my code and still the same... Any tip?